# pandas - optimal row selection over intercolumn conditional

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
            dataPoint   RIC ExpirationDate          Exchange Description  \
closingDate                                                                
2002-10-15       4207  SPH3     2003-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15       5400  SPH4     2004-03-18  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15      18661  SPM3     2003-06-19  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15      19918  SPM4     2004-06-17  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15      33439  SPU3     2003-09-18  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15      35523  SPU4     2004-09-16  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15      47733  SPZ2     2002-12-19  CME:Index and Options Market   
2002-10-15      49022  SPZ3     2003-12-18  CME:Index and Options Market
```

I want to grab the row with an ExpirationDate closest to my closingDate (note that I have the static closingDate stored in a variable called current_date).

df.iterrows() is one solution that comes to mind, but it seems inefficient. Is there an optimal method of doing this conditional selection?

Comment: Maybe something like `row_number = (df['ExpirationDate'] - current_date).dt.total_seconds().abs().idxmin()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of the minimum absolute difference and index.

```
v = pd.to_datetime(df.reset_index()['ExpirationDate'])
idx = (v.mask(v < current_date) 
           - pd.to_datetime(current_date)).abs().idxmin()
row = df.iloc[idx, :]
```

I see one problem here: If your index values are not unique, then you will need to index on position and not label. For that reason, I add the `reset_index` call.

Comment: Is there a reason to do `df.iloc[idx, :]` over just `df.iloc[idx]`?

Comment: @ajwood No, just being thorough and explicit about the indexing. They're both the same.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I only want the forward closest date, and if I'm not mistaking this code will look both directions. How can I account for this?